# Spark streaming using MQTTutils to subscribe topic from activemq with authentication

Tags: authentication, mqtt, spark-streaming

It seems MQTTUtils Only provide three methods,
def createStream(jssc: JavaStreamingContext, brokerUrl: String, topic: String, storageLevel: StorageLevel): JavaDStream[String]

Create an input stream that receives messages pushed by a MQTT publisher.
def createStream(jssc: JavaStreamingContext, brokerUrl: String, topic: String): JavaDStream[String]

Create an input stream that receives messages pushed by a MQTT publisher.
def createStream(ssc: StreamingContext, brokerUrl: String, topic: String, storageLevel: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2): DStream[String]

Create an input stream that receives messages pushed by a MQTT publisher.

But How can I provide username and password if the broker enabled authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You could try including the username and password in the url:

mqtt://username:password@host:port

Comment: Tried with mqtt and tcp schemas on the url with credentials. 

With mqtt schema gives a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` and with tcp schema gives a `java.net.UnknownHostException`

Answer (score 0):

Please find this [MQTT Scala Word Count Example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.0/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/MQTTWordCount.scala).

Particular for your case run the publisher as

```
bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.MQTTPublisher mqtt://username:password@host:port foo
```

And Subscriber as

```
bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.MQTTWordCount mqtt://username:password@host:port foo
```

Before doing this ensure that you are started ActiveMQ broker.

example code

```
import org.apache.activemq.broker.{TransportConnector, BrokerService}
.
.
.
.
def startActiveMQMQTTBroker() {
    broker = new BrokerService()
    broker.setDataDirectoryFile(Utils.createTempDir())
    connector = new TransportConnector()
    connector.setName("mqtt")
    connector.setUri(new URI("mqtt:" + brokerUri))
    broker.addConnector(connector)
    broker.start()
}
```

pom file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using the customized spark-streaming-mqtt-connector library available here - https://github.com/sathipal/spark-streaming-mqtt-with-security_2.10-1.3.0.

This library adds the following on top of the original library,

- Added TLS v1.2 security such that the communication is always secured.
- Stored topic along with the payload in the RDD.

So, use the following method to create the stream,

```
val lines = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, // Spark Streaming Context
            "ssl://URL",                // Broker URL
            "<topic>",                 // MQTT topic
            "MQTT client-ID",          // Unique ID of the application
            "Username", 
            "passowrd")
```

There are overloaded constructors that allows you to pass the RDD storage level as well. Hope this helps.