# Spark Streaming from MQTT - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq, pyspark, spark-streaming, mqtt

I'm trying to consume messages from RabbitMQ in Spark Streaming following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172737/1344854. I'm failing with `IllegalArgumentException` and I don't know why.

```
6/09/05 13:23:22 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ssl://user:password@bunny.cloudamqp.com:8883/vhost
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateURI(MqttConnectOptions.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.mqtt.MQTTReceiver.onStart(MQTTInputDStream.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried passing various combinations of `brokerUrl` argument to the `MQTTUtils.createStream` constructor including tcp:
`tcp://user:password@bunny.cloudamqp.com:1883/vhost`

Why is it failing to validate and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/27777998/2677943 ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how exactly can this be helpful as it seems to be outside Python context. Python `MQTTUtils` API looks like this: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.2/python/pyspark/streaming/mqtt.py#L30 There is no space for extra credential args, nothing :/

Comment: Well, looks as if there is currently no way to do it in python and, with your spark version, in scala it will only be possible with external libraries... Sooner or later I will run into the very same issue with my current project. Guess I will just try to update spark and switch to scala.

Comment: Actually I tried with spark 2.0.0 but there, even `mqtt` module is missing. So I downgraded to experiment with 1.6.2. What is your use-case?

Comment: As of 2.0 some unpopular streaming backends have been moved to Spark packages. There is also opened PR including authentication: https://github.com/spark-packages/dstream-mqtt/pull/2 although it doesn't provide Python wrappers and it looks like it can break quite a few thing.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even consider it a feature without authentication covered out of the box. All in all, seems like Kafka is the most "native" way to talk with Spark.

Comment: Yes, looks like it has been moved to [bahir](https://github.com/apache/bahir) which seems to have authentication support but still not in the python interface.